# Is it possible to extract text from screen using the function ExtTextOut?

Tags: c++, winapi, extract

I would like to ba able to extraxt text from what is on my screen using the function ExtTextOut but I am a rookie in C++. I am using Qt and I would like to have a simple example that I could reproduce in my code when I need to extract text. For example, if I want to extract this text and stock it in a document, how can I do it?

I wrote the short code below, but I don't know how to go further?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <windows.h>
#include <QCursor>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QCursor::setPos(20,100);
exttextout(20,100);
return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: ExtTextOut *draws* text.  The "Ext" stands for "extended".  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: As @arx pointed out, ExtTextOut draws text.  It's not a function you can use to extract text.  I think you need to restate your question.  Be more explicit in telling us what you want to do.

Comment: Also, you can't mix Windows API functions like `ExtTextOut` (or similar) with QT.

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick reply! Yes you're right, I may not be explicit enough. I would like to extract data published on my screen by a software or a web page and write them in a file like notepad. Maybe EM_STREAMOUT would be useful? It seems that i can use it with Qt. I am looking for a simple example that I could adapt easily.

Comment: Information on your screen is in pixels, not text.  To get text, you need to be able to either access it from the application which drew it, or else do character recognition on the screen image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The ExtTextOut() function draws text using the currently selected font, background color, and text color. You can optionally provide dimensions to be used for clipping, opaquing, or both.

```
BOOL ExtTextOut(
  _In_  HDC hdc,
  _In_  int X,
  _In_  int Y,
  _In_  UINT fuOptions,
  _In_  const RECT *lprc,
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpString,
  _In_  UINT cbCount,
  _In_  const INT *lpDx
);
```

`hdc [in]`
A handle to the device context.

`X [in]`
The x-coordinate, in logical coordinates, of the reference point used to position the string.

`Y [in]`
The y-coordinate, in logical coordinates, of the reference point used to position the string.

`fuOptions [in]`
Specifies how to use the application-defined rectangle. This parameter can be one or more of the following values.

[For more details visit the MSDN forum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911411.aspx)
.

```
exttextout(20,100);
```

is a blunder and you can't read text from screen just like that. You have to use some image processing software in order to do that. I think it would be a better option if you could club MATLAB with your program.